# How to open audio file when i am swiping between layouts?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, audio

I am using [this code](https://gist.github.com/luksprog/4476966) to swipe between layouts and I would like it to open audio files.
I try to work it so: I swiped from first to second layout, and when layout second came, it should open an audio file.
I tried to use "**switch**", but I don't know how to properly implement it.
Thanks!

I have done this!
Just add **OnPageChangeListener** to code.
So it will look like:

```
     mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int page) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
            case 0: //first layout
                audio1.start();
                break;
            case 1: //second layout
                audio2.start();
                break;
                 //other case, other layouts
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: Code for questions is required to be in the question for future readers because links have a tendency to get deleted.  Also, questions need to be pretty specific.  As this is written, it is difficult to know what code, what problem, what error message, what did you expect instead.  You can help others to help you by making it clearer what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should declare a `MediaPlayer` object within your switch block, give it an `Uri` containing your audio file path and play your file.

```
public void moveTo(View v) {
        // switch the ViewPager according to the button clicked
        int page = 0;

        Uri songUri = Uri.parse("musicPath");
        player = MediaPlayer.create(context, songUri);
        player.start();

        switch (v.getId()) {

        [...]
```

I do not know if your music file is like just a few seconds long sound or a whole music track but if it is the first case, it is the best way.

Comment: But how to do this not on button press, and when just swipe?

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood your request. First, does your layouts swipe correctly?

Comment: Then call the three lines I wrote within your layout swipe function. When swipe will be called, your sound will be played.

Comment: Okay. I got it. But is here any way to call different audio on different layouts?

Comment: Do some researches but it is the best way to play an audio file